# QGIS Standalone Installer Version 3.12 download link for Windows is not found on server

Tags: qgis, download, link

I have tried to download QGIS 3.12 for Windows from https://qgis.org/downloads/QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.12.3-2-Setup-x86_64.exe but the server don't found the file.

Can you tell me how can I download this QGIS version?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 3.12.3-1 link:

https://download.osgeo.org/qgis/windows/QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.12.3-1-Setup-x86_64.exe

Answer (score 1):

The network installer is quite unreliable. You can download the QGIS offline standalone installer from the following link:

https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html

It is under the section "Long term release repository (most stable)"

Direct download link: [here](https://qgis.org/downloads/QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.16.4-1-Setup-x86_64.exe)